# Booster Circuit Input Capacitance Design

Tags: dc-dc-converter, capacitance, converter

I am trying to design a booster circuit. I need to find the inductance, output capacitance and input capacitance. I have successfully calculated the inductance and output capacitance. However, I am struggling to find the input capacitance. I have looked at numnerous online resources to obtain a formula for it, however, most say: "input capacitance isn't really important, I_rms is more relevant". I'm not really interested in I_rms, but rather C_in. The formula provided, yields non-viable answers:

[image]

Where I_in = I_inductor (which I have found). However, I am slightly confused by the input voltage ripple. It is mentioned that a "A KEITHLEY 2231A-30-3 Triple Channel DC power supply" is used. So I looked up the datasheet for it (found [here](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1884835.pdf)). From the datasheet the input voltage ripple is 5mVpk-pk. Using this and I_in (0.682 A). I get an enormous capacitance value (roughly 26,000uF). This is not near any of the components that I have been given (available max capacitor: 2200uF).

Input voltage is 30V and desired output voltage is 48V with an `f` of 25 kHz. Further, I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266631/input-capacitor-selection-for-boost-converter) page on stack exchange where the last answer mentions input capacitance values of roughly 100uF are usually used in boosters. This leads me to believe that either the formula provided is incorrect or the value of the ripple voltage is incorrect.

Being a newbie, I am not entirely sure what sort of ripple values should be expected for an input source and not really sure about the formula either as I haven't found a proof for it yet.

Circuit Topology:
[image]

Workings:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to see the topology of your intended schematic and I'd like to see your calculation process. This will expose a number of important details. Would that be something you could consider, here? (I could assume some things, but I'd rather not.) Equations are rigorously derived *from* theory deduced into specific circumstances. I can know the theory well enough, but without the specifics it isn't really wise to attempt deductions. So details are important.

Comment: Yep sure, should I just add the topology onto the original question? And adding the calculations could make the question too long. Is it ok if I tack them on as images?

Comment: There is a schematic editor available when you edit the question. I'd rather you use that. It will label parts for clarity. If you have a very clear schematic topology that comes complete with part numbering, then I suppose you could bypass the editor. Also, the calculations would *not* (my opinion only) make the question too long. They are important. If you add them as an image, make sure the image is very very readable. If it is the least bit difficult, I won't bother. (Can't speak to others, though.)

Comment: The input capacitance is not relevant without more information on the voltage source. (The reason is simple. If the voltage source is perfect, then there's no need for the input capacitance. It will be the less-than-perfect details about the voltage source that *partly* determine the input capacitance.) Is this input source a diode bridged transformer secondary?

Comment: The input source is a triple channel DC power supply
This is what other sources have told me "input capaacitance isn't relevant". However, part fo the design is to calculate the value of it. I have also added teh workings now @jonk

Comment: I've +1'd the question now, too. And yes, using a triple supply (I have three Tektronix PS2520G's for example) pretty much qualifies as "computing an input capacitance is no longer relevant" to my mind. There is no formula to deduce from theory, here. The power supply does all the heavy lifting for you. So you move on from there.